# Nginx variable in proxy pass does not work

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Can proxy_pass work with variables? I am trying to make the below configuration work:

```
    http {
       ...

        map $http_user_agent $myvariable {
            default 'mobile';    

        }

       ...
    }
```

The location configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;

   ...

    location /site {        
            proxy_pass http://docker-site/site/$myvariable;
        }

   ...
}
```

The configuration works if I replace the proxy_pass with `http://docker-site/site/mobile;`

Let me know if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two cases are not the same. If you use a variable, that value will replace the entire URI.

In this case:

```
location /site { 
    proxy_pass http://docker-site/site/mobile;
}
```

the URI `/site/foo` is passed upstream as `/site/mobile/foo`.

To use your variable, you can use a rewrite (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details):

```
location /site { 
    rewrite ^/site(.*)$ /site/$myvariable$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://docker-site;
}
```

Or a regular expression location:

```
location ~ ^/site(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://docker-site/site/$myvariable$1;
}
```

The evaluation order of regular expression location blocks is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: thankyou for the prompt response. Using the rewrite one I am facing the error that `localhost redirected you too many times` if I try to access `localhost/site` where my server tries to redirect me to `localhost/site/login`. Although if I bypass the login then it works fine. Any idea? (P.S : I don't have enough rep to upvote this answer)

Comment: this answer correctly explains the approach to tackle the above question. regarding the 302 bit i will ask a separate questions. thanks.

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://docker-site/site/$myvariable$uri`